# Cypress/GitLab CI/CD integration - Cypress won't start in headless mode

Tags: gitlab, cypress

After writing several tests in Cypress and trying them out locally in both headless and headed way (both work great) I can't get our GitLab to start up Cypress in headless way after inserting the test in the integration process. This seems to be an issue:
`[FAILED] Your system is missing the dependency: Xvfb`
Why would I need Xvfb for running headless test in Cypress? I'm stuck on this for two days now, any help or idea would be greatly appreciated.

test config in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
test:
  image: node:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm start &
    - npm test
```

relevant lines from package.json:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 4222 -o"
"test": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/test_zber/test.spec.js"
```

gitlab output when trying to run the test after successfully going through `npm ci`

```
$ npm start &
$ npm test
> sdcl@0.1.30 start
> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 4222 -o
> sdcl@0.1.30 test
> cypress run --spec cypress/integration/test_zber/test.spec.js
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 8.6.0
[STARTED] Task without title.
[FAILED] Your system is missing the dependency: Xvfb
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Install Xvfb and run Cypress again.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Read our documentation on dependencies for more information:
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Error: spawn Xvfb ENOENT
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Platform: linux (Debian - 10.11)
[FAILED] Cypress Version: 8.6.0
Your system is missing the dependency: Xvfb
Install Xvfb and run Cypress again.
Read our documentation on dependencies for more information:
https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.
----------
Error: spawn Xvfb ENOENT
----------
Platform: linux (Debian - 10.11)
Cypress Version: 8.6.0
Warning: Entry point 'ng2-ace-editor' contains deep imports into '/builds/D7tLJUkz/0/uvz/evz/sdc/sdcl-fe/node_modules/brace/theme/monokai'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
```

console output when running this locally:

```
PS C:\projectlocation> npm test

> sdcl@0.1.30 test C:\projectlocation
> cypress run --spec cypress/integration/test_zber/test.spec.js


[10644:1014/090627.480:ERROR:display_layout.cc(559)] PlacementList must be sorted by first 8 bits of display_id

====================================================================================================

  (Run Starting)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:    8.6.0                                                                              │
  │ Browser:    Electron 93 (headless)                                                             │
  │ Specs:      1 found (test_zber/test.spec.js)                                                   │
  │ Searched:   cypress\integration\test_zber\test.spec.js                                         │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Running:  test_zber/test.spec.js                                                          (1 of 1)


  simple_statement_test
    √ test1 (3090ms)
    √ test2 (4969ms)
    √ test3 (882ms)
    √ test4 (2489ms)
    √ test5 (503ms)


  5 passing (14s)


  (Results)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Tests:        5                                                                                │
  │ Passing:      5                                                                                │
  │ Failing:      0                                                                                │
  │ Pending:      0                                                                                │
  │ Skipped:      0                                                                                │
  │ Screenshots:  0                                                                                │
  │ Video:        true                                                                             │
  │ Duration:     13 seconds                                                                       │
  │ Spec Ran:     test_zber/test.spec.js                                                           │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


  (Video)

  -  Started processing:  Compressing to 32 CRF
  -  Finished processing: C:\projectlocation\cypress\videos\test_zber\test.     (1 second)
                          spec.js.mp4


====================================================================================================

  (Run Finished)


       Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped  
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ √  test_zber/test.spec.js                   00:13        5        5        -        -        - │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    √  All specs passed!                        00:13        5        5        -        -        -
```

Comment: How about you run the command with xvfb-run wrapped - `xvfb-run npx cypress run`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to use docker image provided by Cypress guide at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/gitlab-ci#Testing-in-Chrome-and-Firefox-with-Cypress-Docker-Images

Config in .gitlab.ci.yml

```
test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node12.14.1-chrome85-ff81
  stage: test
  script:
    # install dependencies
    - npm ci
    # start the server in the background
    - npm start &
    # run Cypress tests
    - npx cypress run --browser chrome
```

Comment: You can use a new image 

image: cypress/browsers:node-20.9.0-chrome-118.0.5993.88-1-ff-118.0.2-edge-118.0.2088.46-1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the `--headless` option to `cypress run` command? I don't see it in the question, but it does seem as a solution based on some other questions asked here on SO, e.g. this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66373352/bitbucket-pipeline-your-system-is-missing-the-dependency-xvfb). You can find this option in documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-headless).

Another solution could be to use an official Cypress Docker image or installing the `Xvfb` package before running Cypress.

Comment: `--headless`  is default option for `cypress run` and in the terminal output ran locally, it even explicitly states it's headless. `Browser:    Electron 93 (headless)`  it's only on GitLab CI it wants to install `Xvfb`

Answer (score 0):

I was using cypress to test a nextJS (React) application. For me the docker image in the cypress guide did not work, because nextJS requires a newer version of node. If you go to [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/browsers) GitHub repository you can find many more usefull docker images.

In the end this worked form me:

In .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: cypress/browsers:node14.16.0-chrome89-ff86

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    # install dependencies
    - npm ci
    # start the server in the background
    - npm run start:ci &
    # run Cypress tests
    - npm run test:ci
```

Do not forget to define the used scripts in package.json :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start:ci": "next dev",
    "test:ci": "cypress run"
  },
}
```